# Menu link tree only loads enabled elements in subtree regardless of parameters

Tags: navigation, 9

When loading a menu tree without any custom parameters:

```
$tree = \Drupal::menuTree()->load('my-menu-name', new MenuTreeParameters());
```

The returned tree `\Drupal\Core\Menu\MenuLinkTreeElement[]` includes disabled items, which is what I want. I did not set `onlyEnabledLinks()` or `addCondition('enabled', 1)` to the MenuTreeParameters.

For some reason, though, every `subtree` returned beyond the root level excludes disabled items. Even if I re-query each subtree, it still happens:

```
foreach ($tree as $element) {
    
    // Do stuff
    
    $parameters = new MenuTreeParameters();
    $parameters->setRoot($element->link->getPluginId())->excludeRoot();
    $subtree = \Drupal::menuTree()->load('my-menu-name', $parameters);
}
```

The only way I have found to include disabled items so far has been to re-query each subtree twice with `$parameters->addCondition('enabled', 1);` and `$parameters->addCondition('enabled', 0);`, which is ridiculous.

I can't find anything in the documentation to suggest this is the correct behavior of Drupal, but I'm hoping someone can spot something I'm missing before I submit a bug report. This is in Drupal 9.1.

Comment: This is not the behavior I see - I see the disabled items in my subtrees.

Comment: I uninstalled all modules except core and used the default theme, and this still happens. Are there any other sources of potential menu manipulation I am missing?

Comment: @sonfd Can you confirm you're using Drupal 9.1?

Comment: I may have originally been on 8.9 (not sure), but I did just test on 9.1.4 with minimal install and I'm seeing all items in the tree. I have a `hook_preprocess_page()` with  `$tree = \Drupal::menuTree()->load('admin', new MenuTreeParameters());` with a breakpoint on the next line. I've disabled Structure and Structure > Display Modes menu items. When I load a page and hit my breakpoint, I see the whole tree in my var, disabled items and their subtrees included. (Sorry I'm so slow getting back to you.)

Comment: Most likely related to https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/3202930